# How to provide the arguement -Xshare:off to the java command starting the application

Tags: tomcat, visualvm

I have a Application running under Tomcat .

I want to profile this Application (VisualVM ----> CPU Sampler), as part of that when i launched  VisualVM under java bin directory

I was seeing the following Message

**Class sharing is enabled for this JVM" warning is shown in red box in Profiler tab**

Under the below link , the following resolution is mentioned

https://visualvm.java.net/troubleshooting.html

Resolution:  There is a known problem with dynamic attach which is used for profiling, it may cause target JVM to crash when class sharing is enabled. 
To start an application without class sharing, provide **-Xshare:off** argument to the java command starting the application.

Could anybody please let me know how to resolve this .

Answer (score 0):

```
$ export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xshare:off"
$ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start
```

If you are using a Microsoft Windows service, run `CATALINA_HOME/bin/tomcatXw.exe` (where X is your Tomcat version) and edit the launcher arguments to include `-Xshare:off`.